# Java 8 UTF-16 isn't default charset but UTF-8

Tags: java, string, utf-8, utf-16

I been doing some coding with String in Java8,Java 11 but this question is based on Java 8. I have this little snippet.

```
final char e = (char)200;//È
```

I just thought that the characters between 0.255[Ascii+extended Ascii] would always fit in a byte just because 2^8=256 but this seems not to be true i have try on the website https://mothereff.in/byte-counter and states that the character is taking 2 bytes can somebody please explain to me.

Another question in a lot of post states that Java is UTF-16 but in my machine running Windows 7 is returning UTF-8 in this snippet.

```
String csn = Charset.defaultCharset().name();
```

Is this platform depent?

Other questions i have try this snippet.

```
final List<Charset>charsets = Arrays.asList(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1,StandardCharsets.US_ASCII,StandardCharsets.UTF_16,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    charsets.forEach(a->print(a,"È"));
    System.out.println("getBytes");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString("È".getBytes()));
    charsets.forEach(a->System.out.println(a+" "+Arrays.toString(sb.toString().getBytes(a))));

private void print(final Charset set,final CharSequence sb){
    byte[] array = new byte[4];              
    set.newEncoder()
            .encode(CharBuffer.wrap(sb), ByteBuffer.wrap(array), true);
    final String buildedString = new String(array,set);
    System.out.println(set+" "+Arrays.toString(array)+" "+buildedString+"<<>>"+buildedString.length());    
}
```

And prints

```
run:
ISO-8859-1 [-56, 0, 0, 0] È//PERFECT USING 1 BYTE WHICH IS -56
US-ASCII [0, 0, 0, 0] //DONT GET IT SEE THIS ITEM FOR LATER
UTF-16 [-2, -1, 0, -56] È<<>>1 //WHAT IS -2,-1 BYTE USED FOR? I HAVE TRY WITH OTHER EXAMPLES AND THEY ALWAYS APPEAR AM I LOSING TWO BYTES HERE??
UTF-8 [-61, -120, 0, 0] 2 È //SEEMS TO MY CHARACTER NEEDS TWO BYTES?? I THOUGHT THAT CODE=200 WOULD REQUIRE ONLY ONE
getBytes
[-61, -120]//OK MY UTF-8 REPRESENTATION
ISO-8859-1 [-56]//OK
US-ASCII [63]//OK BUT WHY WHEN I ENCODE IN ASCCI DOESNT GET ANY BYTE ENCODED?
UTF-16 [-2, -1, 0, -56]//AGAIN WHAT ARE -2,-1 IN THE LEADING BYTES?
UTF-8 [-61, -120]//OK
```

I have try

```
System.out.println(new String(new byte[]{-1,-2},"UTF-16"));//SIMPLE "" I AM WASTING THIS 2 BYTES??
```

In resume.

1. Why UTF-16 always has two leading bytes are they wasted? new byte[]{-1,-2}
2. Why when i encode "È" i dont get any bytes in ASCCI Charset but when i do È.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII) i get {63}?
3. Java uses UTF-16 but in my case UTF-8 is platform depend??

Sorry if this post is confussing

Environment

```
Windows 7 64 Bits Netbeans 8.2 with Java 1.8.0_121
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First question**

For your first question: those bytes are the BOM code and they specify the byte order (whether the least or most significant comes first) of multibyte encoding such as UTF-16.

**Second question**

Every ASCII character can be encoded as a single byte in UTF-8. But ASCII is not an 8-bit encoding, it uses 7 bits for every character. And in fact, all Unicode character with code points >= 128 require at least two bytes. (The reason is that you need a way to distinguish between 200 and a multibyte code point whose first byte happens to be 200. UTF-8 solves this by using the bytes >= 128 to represent multibyte codepoints.)

'È' is not an ASCII character, so it cannot be represented in ASCII. This explains the second output: 63 is ASCII for the character '?'. And indeed, the Javadoc for the `getBytes(Charset)` method specifies that unmappable input is mapped to "the default replacement byte array", in this case '?'. On the other hand, to obtain the first ASCII byte array you used the `CharsetEncoder` directly, which is a more low-level API and does not perform such automatic replacements. (When you would have checked the result of the `encode` method, you would have found it to have returned a `CoderResult` instance representing an error.)

**Third question**

Java 8 `String`s use UTF-16 internally, but when communicating with other software, different encodings may be expected, such as UTF-8. The `Charset.defaultCharset()` method returns the default character set of the virtual machine, which depends on the locale and character set of the operating system, not on the encoding used internally by Java strings.

Comment: The OS is not concerned with the user's current choice of character encoding. Windows API uses UTF-16; The file system uses UTF-16, The GUI system uses UTF-16. All it does is allow the user to choose one and make that choice available to programs. It is up to them to decide if that choice reflects the user's intentions about how the encode/decode text files. Sure some such programs are provided by the operating system, such as cmd.exe. Notepad.exe turns it around and offers it back the user along with UTF-8, UTF-16LE and UTF-16BE. And old programs like `javac` use it too unless told otherwise.

Comment: @Tom Blodget. Thank you for your comment. I rephrased the paragraph.

Comment: thanks how can i throw a exception when a character is not allowed? and how {-1,-2} BOM can be interpreted i mean does have a special meaning a pattern to Java recognize it like a BOM?

Answer (score 1):

Let's back up a bit…

Java's text datatypes use the UTF-16 character encoding of the Unicode character set. (As do, VB4/5/6/A/Script, JavaScript, .NET, ….) You can see this in the various operations you do with the string API: indexing, length, ….

Libraries support converting between the text datatypes and byte arrays using various encodings. Some of them are categorized as "Extended ASCII", but stating that is a very poor substitute for naming the character encoding actually being used.

Some operating systems allow the user to designate a default character encoding. (Most users don't know or care, though.) Java attempts to pick this up. It is only useful when the program understands that input from the user is that character encoding or that output should be. This century, users dealing in text files prefer to use a specific encoding, communicate them unchanged across systems, don't appreciate lossy conversions and therefore don't have any use for this concept. From a program's point of view, it is never what you want unless it is exactly what you want.

Where a conversion would be lossy, you have the choice of a replacement character (such a '?'), omitting it, or throwing an exception.

A character encoding is a map between a codepoint (integer) of a character set and one or more code units, according to the definition of the encoding. A code unit is a fixed size and the number of code units needed for a codepoint, might vary by codepoint.

In libraries, it is not generally useful to have an array of code units so they take the further step of converting to/from an array of bytes. `byte` values do range from -128 to 127, however, that's the Java interpretation as two's complement 8-bit integers. As the bytes are understood to be encoding text, the values would be interpret according to the rules of the character encoding.

Because some Unicode encodings, have code units more than one byte long, byte order becomes important. So, at the byte array level, there is UTF-16 Big Endian and UTF-16 Little Endian. When communicating a text file or stream, you would send the bytes and well as having a shared knowledge of the encoding. This "metadata" is required for understanding. So, UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE, for example. To make that a bit easier, Unicode allows some metadata beginning of the file or stream to indicate the byte order. It is called the byte-order mark (BOM) So, the external metadata can share the encoding (say, UTF-16), while the internal metadata shares the byte order. Unicode allows the BOM to be present even when byte order is not relevant, such as UTF-8. So, if the understanding is that the bytes are text encoded with any Unicode encoding and a BOM is present, then it's a very simple matter to figure out which Unicode encoding it is and what the byte order is, if relavent.

1) You are seeing the BOM in some of your Unicode encoding outputs.

2) È is not in the ASCII character set. What would want to happen in this case? I often prefer an exception.

3) The system you were using, for your account, at the time of your tests, may have had UTF-8 as the default character encoding, Is that important to the way you want and have encoded your text files on that system?

Comment: thanks how can i throw a exception when a character is not allowed?